# mkmapview crashing in IOS 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview

This is karthik. I am getting this following error when i run my application. When my application trying to find the user location its crashing. Actually in **IOS 4.0** and **4.1** its working fine. Only in 4.2 its crashing. Can you help me?

> CoreAnimation: ignoring exception:
>   (null) must implement title when
>   canShowCallout is YES on correspoding
>   view > visible:0 +0.00000000, +0.00000000 2011-05-09 12:32:40.631 HOV[1821:207] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: '>
>   visible:0 +38.91791916, -77.20580292
>   must implement title when
>   canShowCallout is YES on correspoding
>   view > visible:0 +38.91791916, -77.20580292'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:

Answer (score 3):

You should do exactly what the error text tells you to: your MkAnnotation delegate should implement

```
- (NSString*)title
```

method, which provides the text to be shown in the callout view.
The method is optional and is called only if you set canShowCallout to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Check the title in the annotation view. I think title is set to null some times...

Answer (score 0):

Check all the annotations that are plotted. I think there is a case where an annotation does not have a title which leads to this crash. Check if all the annotations have values for title.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when running on iOS 4.2.1.  The app did not crash on iOS 5.x.  I also made sure that the Annotations used all implemented `title` method.

It turned out that the annotation passed to `selectAnnotation:animated:` was nil at that time.

This explains why the error message mentions **(null)**.  iOS 4.2.1 appears to check for the `title` method even if the annotation is not defined.

```
CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: (null) must implement title when canShowCallout is YES on correspoding view
```

So this was fixed by making sure annotation was not nil before calling `selectAnnotation:animated:`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case the method `-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)ann{ }` was being called twice. So I put the following code there which worked for me:

```
if (myAnnotation == annotation) {

    [pinView setCanShowCallout:YES];

}
```